# How to find the load resistor's resistance?

Tags: resistors, load

[image]

Use max power transfer theorem to calculate the value of RL for the following circuit.

I've done the Thevenin's equivalent circuit but from there I don't know how to find the \$R_{Load}\$.  I need it to do a table of current and power against \$R_{Load}\$.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can "find" \$R_{Load}\$.  You don't have a current or the voltage on \$R_{Load}\$, so I don't see any way for you to calculate \$R_{Load}\$.  Is there some part of the assignment you haven't shared with us?

Comment: the question is to make a Table of Current against Power like this https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/dccircuits/dcp_9.html                       and i thought i would need the Rload to do it?

Comment: Yes, you need \$R_{Load}\$ to figure out how much current flows through it and how much power it dissipates.  I just don't think you have enough given information to calculate \$R_{Load}\$.  You need one of the following: 1. Another given voltage. 2. A given current. 3. Given \$R_{Load}\$

Comment: Why dont you use  KVL and KCL instead of Thevenin's Theorem for start? Do this with $$R_{load}$$  to be a variable and then solve for that variable.

Comment: Use max power transfer theorem to calculate the value of RL for the following circuit. (This is the question it that helps)

Comment: @oritem8:  That belongs in the question.  That's the missing bit of information.

Comment: @oritem8 ***YES*** that helps! It's ***everything*** to the question at hand. Place that additional piece into your question. Failing to add something like that is what causes confusion and a complete waste of everyone's time, beforehand. Adding it saves everyone a lot of consternation.

Comment: huh i still dont undertand

Comment: Edit your question.  Add the part about "Use max power transfer theorem to calculate the value of RL for the following circuit" to the question.  Someone will then explain to you how it all hangs together.

Comment: And so, you have the thevenin equivalent of the system except the load, right? And what does the maximum power theorem say? The maximum power is reached when there is a specific condition of load and source? What is the condition?

Comment: Are RS and RL equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ["maximum power transfer theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem) tells you that for maximum power transfer, the load resistance must be the same as the source resistance.

You've used Thevenin's theorem to find the source resistancee.  Given that and the statement above about the maximum power transfer theorem, you should be able to figure out \$R_{Load}\$ pretty easily.

From that you can find the current through the circuit and the current through \$R_{Load}\$.

With the current through \$R_{Load}\$, you can find the dissipated power using the formula for [Joule heating.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance#Energy_dissipation_and_Joule_heating)  That's \$P_{Load} = I_{Load}^2R_{Load}\$

Comment: @relayman357 Impedance is the correct term to use for general rule here

Answer (score 0):

Zout = 3.61K +10 K therefore if a 13.61K load is applied, it will reduce the 4.xxx Vo in half.

You choose whatever load you need.

High Z for low voltage loss or matched Z for max power transfer.

Comment: Did this not answer your question?